# Where is documentation for [ x$feature_... = xy ] in grub.cfg?

Tags: grub2, bash

I can't find any reference of x$feature... using Google as it will show me examples of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

In self-generated grub.cfg, there is a lot of

```
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ] ...

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy]...

if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]...
```

My understanding is that it is checking if the feature is present. Where can I find every feature available with description.

I assume `xy` means something like true or available. What other values can you have?

Edit: I only need to know the variables available in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Preferably a documentation.

Comment: See here: [How to determine if a bash variable is empty](http://serverfault.com/questions/7503/how-to-determine-if-a-bash-variable-is-empty)

Comment: @wjandrea, this is not a `bash`. It is `GRUB` thought it may look completely like a `bash`.

Answer (score 7):

`feature_platform_search_hint` (and others) and the shell-like syntax are a feature of the `normal` module in `grub`. The syntax is somewhat documented in the [GRUB manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Shell_002dlike-scripting) - although I couldn't find documentation for `[]` The script language is "obviously" modelled after bash, as it reserves words used in bash even if not yet implemented (such as `[[`) and implements bashisms such as `function`.

The predefined variables such as `feature_platform_search_hint` are hardcoded in the normal module at build time, and are essentially undocumented except by studying the source code. In current versions of `grub`, these variables are  defined to be `y` at all times, so these variables seem to indicate support for specific features of a given grub version, and testing them can be done to write `grub.cfg` files that work with multiple versions of grub.

For example, `feature_platform_search_hint=y` seems to indicate that the search command supports `--hint-bios`, `--hint-efi` and so on switches, while the absence of this variable might indicate a version of `grub` that doesn't support these switches, so you shouldn't try to execute a `search` statement using them to avoid syntax errors.

There is a lot of conjecture and "may" in my answer, as all of this seems to be essentially undocumented.

Answer (score 7):

The syntax is described in [the GRUB manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Shell_002dlike-scripting) as "a syntax quite similar to that of GNU Bash and other Bourne shell derivatives". Quoting and variable expansion work similar as in the shell. The opening bracket "`[`" is a synonym for GRUB's [test builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#g_t_005b).

The list of features is maintained as `features` global variable in [`normal/main.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/log/grub-core/normal/main.c). `feature_platform_search_hint` has been available since GRUB 2.00 (released 2012). So the conditional code checking for this feature is pointless in all modern Linux distributions.

At the time of this writing, the latest feature added was `feature_timeout_style`, available since 2.02-beta1.

Comment: The first constant mentioned in question is declared somewhere around this line - http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/grub-core/normal/main.c#n505 .

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, expression wise, `if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]` has nothing to do with `grub`, it's a  shell expression, to be interpreted by shell. `grub` is using it in one of it's helper script, that's it.

`if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]` is basically testing if the variable `feature_platform_search_hint` is expanded to `y`.

**How?**

The `[` is a synonym for command `test` (can be a shell builtin or an external command), used for evaluating expressions.

In `if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]`:

- `[` is testing whether strings `x$feature_platform_search_hint` and `xy` are same
- here `x` is a placeholder, dummy string, exists on both sides
- the variable `$feature_platform_search_hint` is expanded first, the value is added to already existing string `x`, and then the string on left is compared to the string on the right of `=`
- In effect, it is necessarily checking if variable `feature_platform_search_hint` has value `y`
- Here `x` is used so that if the variable `feature_platform_search_hint` is unset or null, then the `[` will exit with an error as `=` requires argument on both side, and without `feature_platform_search_hint`, this will become:

  ```
  if [ = y ]
  ```

  using `x` gets us syntactically correct usage in that case:

  ```
  if [ x = xy ]
  ```

Note that, one should instead use the `-z` test (which tests if the string is of zero length), or `-n` test (non-zero length test), whichever suits best:

```
if [ -n "$feature_platform_search_hint" ]
if [ -z "$feature_platform_search_hint" ]
```

One should also quote variables (although strictly not necessary in this case as presumably the author intended to define/overwrite the variable inside the script only):

```
if [ x"$feature_platform_search_hint" = xy ]
```

Comment: I didn't know you could write variables next to each other in bash without the quotes. I guess the double quotes are for weak quoting only.

Is there a documentation for the variables available in the helper script.

Comment: @Rami double quotes are used to avoid word-splitting, i.e. when you want contents of your variable to be treated as one entity. With quotes variable `$VAR` may expand to one single entity "hello world", but without quotes it may be treated as two - "hello" and "world". Sometimes it's desirable, but often it is not  desirable to have word splitting

Comment: @Serg I knew that. I just didn't know that you can write something like somecharacters$VAR1$VAR2 (without spaces). I assumed it was like php. You need quotes to write variables next to each other with no space in php.

Comment: @Rami oh, you can ! It's used for  concatenating variables all the time, for instance `touch $HOME/some_file`   or `echo  /home/$USER/bin`

Comment: I guess I had a brain fart especially that I was trying to understand all these options in grub.cfg. The documentation is all over the place.

Comment: While this answer provies nice detail on the conjectured syntax of the if statement and test expression ("[]") it unfortunately completely misses the target, as the quetsioon is about GRUB, and neither the if statement not the symbols are interpreted by helper scripts, but are interpreted by grub (as the original poster remarks, it is in grub.cfg, which is interpreted at boot time when no (unix) shell is available)

Comment: As already mentioned by @RememberMonica the very first sentence of the answer is so terribly wrong. The expression is being executed by `GRUB`. It is not for any shell. The `GRUB` itself is has a bash like script processor internally. Some people even say that it starts to become a tiny OS on its own. :)